# MySQL query doesn't work within PHP file

Tags: php, mysql

I have this piece of php - mysql code:

When a user tagged in my database as a woman opens the page it queries the database for some data with the number 1012,1013,1014 else only 1012,1013.

```
// $php_variable=2 

            $SQL_M = "SELECT @gender:=$php_variable, B.id, B.notes, B.time_logged
            FROM database.evs B
            INNER JOIN (select @gender:=0) as Something
            WHERE
            CASE WHEN @gender=2
            THEN (B.items IN ('1012', '1013', '1014'))
            ELSE (B.items IN ('1012', '1013'))
            END
            ORDER BY B.time_logged ASC";


            $result = mysql_query($SQL_M);
            $mycount = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if ($mycount > 0)  {
                while ($mrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    extract($mrow);
                    echo ">>>>".$id."<br/>"
                    //Works locally - not on server.
                }
            }
```

$php_variable is 2.

It should output items with item id in : 1012,1013,1014
Instead it outputs results for items in 1012,1013.

The strange thing is that I tested this query locally (from php and mysql query alone) 
and on the server (Plesk - Mysql) and it runs just fine.

It doesn't run within the php file in the server -also the ORDER is not functioning properly.

*The query that should execute is:*

```
$SQL_M = "SELECT B.id, B.notes, B.time_logged
FROM database.evs B
WHERE B.items IN ('1012', '1013', '1014')
ORDER BY B.time_logged ASC";
```

*Php version: 5.16* (Local and server)
*MySQL version: 5.0.77* (local and server)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why don't you just build the query in php according to the condition? This seems needlessly complicated.

Comment: I agree with you, based on the example I gave. In reality its much more complicated but this simple example doesn't work too. I'm trying to find the reason...

Comment: try echo $SQL_M and execute it from mysql commandline/phpmyadmin
what is $SQL_M real content ?

Comment: I did that. The echo returned the right SQL. Nevertheless I copied it and executed it in PhpMyAdmin and it returned the right results. I cant understand what is the problem when I run it within the php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do it:

```
$SQL_M = "SELECT B.id, B.notes, B.time_logged FROM database.evs B";
if ($php_variable == 2)
{
  $SQL_M .= " WHERE B.items IN ('1012', '1013', '1014')";
}
else
{
  $SQL_M .= " WHERE B.items IN ('1012', '1013')";
}
$SQL_M .= " ORDER BY B.time_logged ASC";
```

This can be written simpler still, but this is just to show the general idea.

Comment: Thanks jeroen, I will do that eventually but I also need to find what is the cause of this behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: @Kabamaru No, I'm afraid (or lucky...) I don't have any experience with building sql statements like that.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I hope I will find the answer someday and may the luck be with me too :)